# Why is badblocks segfaulting?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, segmentation-fault, badblocks

I am trying to check a mounted partition to see if the drive has errors:

```
[root@virtuality ~]# /sbin/badblocks -v /dev/sdb1
Segmentation fault
```

**Uh oh**. What does this mean? Why is `badblocks` segfaulting? Can I fix it?

(System is CentOS release 4.6, drive is an SATA drive)

**EDIT:** Using `strace`:

```
[root@virtuality ~]# strace /sbin/badblocks -v /dev/sdb1
...[snip]...
open("/dev/sdb1", O_RDONLY)             = 3
ioctl(3, BLKGETSIZE, 0x7fbffff878)      = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/dev/sdb1", O_RDONLY)             = 3
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that means it's hosed :( :( :( ... is this your new box that you just stood up or the old one?

Comment: Have you run a memory test lately? (E.g. from the boot menu in SystemRescueCD, in the Ubuntu livecd, etc.)

Comment: for me it was segfaulting because i was specifying too high of a byte size for `-b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out this was a numbskull error, looks like my copy of `badblocks` may have just had a bug.

I ran `yum update` and after that, `badblocks` no longer segfaults.

Answer (score 2):

The last few lines of that `strace` tell a fairly boring tale: `badblocks` opens the drive device, gets its size, closes it, reopens it and then goes off to do some work, which fails in some way `strace` doesn't show. You'd have to use `gdb` or similar to dig deeper.

Your symptom may go away if you unmount the partition so `badblocks` has a stable thing to work on. Obviously this shouldn't be required just to do the read-only test you're attempting, but it wouldn't be the first time that some low-level uncommonly-used operation didn't work as it should.

Bonus: If you unmount the partition, you can use `badblocks -n`, which is far more effective at finding and fixing disk surface problems.

Comment: +1 for good advice, including running `badblocks -n` when the drive is unmounted. (A Virtual Machine has a backup vmkd on this drive so while it's not in use, it's also not easy to umount) Turns out this may have just been a silly mistake, running `yum` to update my system caused the problem to go away.

Comment: Actually, the open() succeeded, as you can see from its return value of 3.  The SIGSEGV happened somewhere in the `badblocks` code, not in a syscall.  In general, you'll never get a SIGSEGV while a syscall is in progress; if anything, you'd get a kernel OOPS.

Comment: Indeed. Removed the speculation based on unindicated nondeterminism.